# How to get User Role for each user in Data access layer in Identity (MVC5)?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Application is of MVC5 Identity based in c#. As observed, `AspNetUserRoles` is not populated in EDMX. Certainly cannot query on it using LINQ.

In Data access layer, having the function `GetAllUsers()`. For each user need to get its role which is mapped in `AspNetUserRoles` table. Able to get all users but not having its role. Hot to get role for each user ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AspNetUserRoles` is a **mapping table (many-to-many),** so it's not generated in EDMX (by design, it does not have `primary key`)

You can get roles of user by using `navigation properties`:

```
user.Include(u => u.Roles); // only need if lazy loading disabled
var roles = user.Roles;
```

Comment: Worked for me. dbContext.AspNetUsers.Include(s=>s.AspNetRoles)